# postgresql 9.3 service not starting

Tags: postgresql

I have postgresql 9.3.13 installed on windows 2008 server. after an unexpected reboot, the service is not starting up. when try to start postgres as windows service i get error

"The postgresql-9.3 - PostgreSQL Server 9.3 service on Local Computer started and then stopped.  Some services stop automatically if they have no work to do."

I verified the rights on data directory as well, since the service is started as network service, network service has all rights on the data directory.

I tried start the service using `pg_ctl` with start command. I get message that server is starting but it is never started. if i check status a PID is given saying server is running. but if i have to stop it using pg_ctl stop command, that wont happen either. it just says "failed".

In logs, i see following logs

> 1. "database system is starting up"
> 2. when i kill PID from task manager : "PID  exited with code 1. aborting startup due to startup failure"
> 3. below is today's log:
>      LOG:  could not open file "postmaster.pid": No such file or directory
>      LOG:  performing immediate shutdown because data directory lock file is invalid
>      LOG:  received immediate shutdown request
>      WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
>      DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
>      HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.

I have tried deleting the postmaster opts and pid files and starting the service as well but no luck!

On the Postgres forum I see many people having similar issue but didn't find any solution.

Comment: Anything in the Postgres logfile or the Windows "Event Viewer"? Try `pg_ctl start ....`. There is no "runservice" command for `pg_ctl`

Comment: i have tried using pg_ctl start... didnt help

Comment: And what was the error you got?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - no error is shown. using pg_ctl says server is starting. when i check status, a PID is also shown but then if I try to stop server that will never happen.